# Change <form> values before submitting

Tags: javascript, c#, html, code-behind

I need to post form to Salesforce to create a case. Before submitting a form depending on which button is clicked I need to change form values.

I created a from which has two buttons, when first button is clicked I am setting time to current time, if second button is clicked I am picking time which is entered by client. Also from code behind I need to get account id and assign it to form value.

```html
 <form runat="server" id="sf_case_form" name="sf_case_form" action="https://test?encoding=UTF-8" method="post">         

        <input hidden="hidden" id="sf_account_id" maxlength="20" runat="server" name="sf_account_id" size="20" type="text" />
        <input type="hidden" id="external" name="external" value="1" />      
        <input hidden="hidden" type="submit" name="submit"/>
         <div class="wrapper wrapper-content p-xs">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="contact-box center-version">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                <div class="ibox-title">
                    <h5>Request Callback</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="ibox-content" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="font-normal">Your phone number</label>
                        <input id="selected_phone_number" name="selected_phone_number" type="text" class="form-control" data-mask="(999) 999-9999" runat="server" placeholder="(999) 999-9999"/>
                    </div>
                    <asp:button style="margin-bottom: 20px" id="btn_call_now"  OnClick="call_now_Click" type="button" runat="server" Text="Call me now" CssClass="btn btn-w-m btn-danger"/>
                    <div class="form-group" id="data_1">
                        <label class="font-normal">Choose your desired date and time to schedule a call</label>
                        <div class="input-group date">
                            <input id="selected_date" name="selected_date" type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" value="03/04/2014"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
                        <input id="selected_time" name="selected_time" type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" value="09:30"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 20px">
                        <asp:button id="btn_schedule_call" type="button" runat="server"  OnClick="schedule_call_Click" Text="Schedule a call" CssClass="btn btn-w-m btn-primary"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        </form>
```

Code behind

```
  protected void call_now_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Set date to current date
            selected_date.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");
            selected_time.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("t");
            post_form();
        }
```

call_now_Click is not getting called and how can I submit a form after values are changed from code behind?

Answer (score 0):

When using

```
<button type="button" onclick="yourFunctionName()">Click Me!</button>
```

add **ClientIDMode="Static"** to your server control to use simpler ID

```
<input ClientIDMode="Static" id="selected_date" name="selected_date" type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" value="03/04/2014"/>
```

add

in the script

```
<script>
function yourFunctionName() {
  document.getElementById('selected_date').value = new Date();
  ....
  ....
   document.form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: tried did not work, function gets called but value not getting assigned to the input.

Comment: Please notice that when changing server state thing thing in the client side, you won't see it in the control itself.
Instead, use the Request.form("the control name")